# I can access my own home folder only with sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo

I am logging in to a machine via ssh. Is it normal that i need sudo for something like `touch ~/test`

Comment: I see this behaviour for every machine that i access. Is this maybe a special group setting? When I create a new user, this can access the home directory normally

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not.

Check the permissions of your home folder

```
ls -lah /home
```

and/or recursively change permissions

```
chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser
```

Also check for `w`-attribute  in the output of `ls -lah /home` to be present for your home folder at least for the user, you are working with.